# Is there a way to filter rows in BigQuery by the contents of an array?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, bigdata, business-intelligence

I have data in a BigQuery table that looks like this:

```
[
    { "id": 1, "labels": [{"key": "a", "value": 1}, {"key": "b", "value": 2}] },
    { "id": 2, "labels": [{"key": "a", "value": 1}, {"key": "b", "value": 3}] },
    // a lot more rows
]
```

My question is, how can I find all rows where `"key" = "a"`, `"value" = 1`, but also `"key" = "b"` and `"value" = 3`?

I've tried various forms of using `UNNEST` but I haven't been able to get it right. The `CROSS JOIN` leaves me with one row for every object in the `labels` array, leaving me unable to query by both of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select *
from mytable
where exists (select 1 from unnest(labels) where key = "a" and value=1)
  and exists (select 1 from unnest(labels) where key = "b" and value=3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is no duplicate entries in labels array - you can use below

```
select *
from `project.dataset.table` t
where 2 = (
  select count(1) 
  from t.labels kv 
  where kv in (('a', 1), ('b', 3))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try parse JSON and then you can apply different filter conditions on it as per your requirements, in following query I have tried to identified which all records have `Key=a` then I tried to identify which record has `value=30` then joined them through `id` :-

```
WITH data1 AS (
SELECT '{ "id": 1, "labels": [{"key": "a", "value": 11}, {"key": "b", "value": 22}] }' as c1
union all
SELECT '{ "id": 2, "labels": [{"key": "a", "value": 10}, {"key": "b", "value": 30}] }' AS C1
) 
select T1.id, T1.C1, T1.key, T2.value from 
(SELECT JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(c1 , "$.id") AS id, 
json_extract_scalar(curSection, '$.value') as value, json_extract_scalar(curSection, '$.key') as key,
        c1 
 FROM data1 tbl LEFT JOIN unnest(json_extract_array(tbl.c1, '$.labels') 
             ) curSection 
where json_extract_scalar(curSection, '$.key')='a') T1,
(
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(c1 , "$.id") AS id, 
json_extract_scalar(curSection, '$.value') as value, json_extract_scalar(curSection, '$.key') as key,
        c1 
 FROM data1 tbl LEFT JOIN unnest(json_extract_array(tbl.c1, '$.labels') 
             ) curSection 
where json_extract_scalar(curSection, '$.value')='30') T2
where T1.id = T2.id
```

Hopefully it may work for you.